# Removing not null objects from JSON response

Tags: java, spring-boot

Removing not null objects from JSON response. Below is the response i am getting from my service.

{
"creationDate": "2017-01-24T14:31:44",
"channel": [
{}
]
}

I want to eliminate channel object or similar null objects from my response.I tried several approach but didn't work for me.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

annotate the channel property like this:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
```